# CouchDB with GoDaddy SSL doesn't work

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

Does anyone know how to set up CouchDB to use a GoDaddy SSL certificate? It looks like it just can't get the intermediate certificate. I've checked it with curl and with SSL Checker and it says it can't get the intermediate cert. I've tried concatenating the cert file with the intermediate cert file just like I do with Apache (which works) and it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind! Apparently erlang really stinks at SSL. I just set up stunnel and it works perfectly.

Comment: I am not understanding this "solution" and I have the same issue.

Comment: @BeeKay I just used stunnel to handle the SSL and didn’t use HTTPS on CouchDB - just HTTP. stunnel is an SSL gateway. I did not use erlang.